# Open screen from Button in Android

Tags: android

I am very new to Java and android apps.
I am trying to open a screen when the user clicks on a button. The button is called "Company"

I have a MainActivity.java and a Company.java

MainActivity looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // If your minSdkVersion is 11 or higher, instead use:
    // getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
/** Called when the user clicks the Company button */
public void onClick(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TheCompany.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

But nothing happens when the user clicks on the button Company. 
I have a Company Java file and a Company XML file, but they don't get called. I suspect it is the way they are being called from here.

Would really appreciate some help. Also let me know if I need to post other bits of code, like the activity_main.xml.
Thanks!

Comment: does your button have the `android:onClick` attribute set?

Comment: Possibly not, where and how I would do that?

Comment: In your xml layout file for the activity, for the button that the code is referring to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open a new  `activity` with his own  `java.class` by a  `button`, just replace this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Company);
btn.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListner(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TheCompany.class)
MainActivity.this.starActivity(activityChangeIntent);
    }
  });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: I have copied your code and it errors in the following line: btn.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListner() with the error message: View.OnClickListner cannot be resolved to a type. It also errors on the line: Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.TheCompany) saying that TheCompany cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: Can you post your `file.xml`? Let me see I'll solve your problem.

Comment: Pier, I sorted this out. All working now! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

the onclick() method is never called!
You have forgotten to set `android:onClick` in you layout xml file or to set the `OnClickListener` programmatically in code (see below):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   View button = findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick (View v){
         startIntent();
      }

  });
     //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // If your minSdkVersion is 11 or higher, instead use:
    // getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
/** Called when the user clicks the Company button */
private void startIntent() {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TheCompany.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to say you have Company.java, but in your intent you are trying to access TheCompany.class. The file name needs to match the public class in your Company.java. So you either need to have a Company.java file with a Company class or TheCompany.java file with TheCompany class.

I suspect this is setup correctly, otherwise if you've added `android:onClick` in your XML file you'd be getting errors.

It's worth posting the XML for the button, sockeqwe is most likely right.

Comment: I am sorry, yes, I do have a TheCompany.Java

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment on other people's answers due to not having reputation. With regards to your reply to Pier's answer: `btn.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListner()` - both Listener words on this line are missing the first e, just a typo. The second error on `(Button)findViewById(R.id.TheCompany)` is because the id of the button inside the XML file is not TheCompany. Make sure you have a line in the XML for your button that says `android:id="@+id/someButtonId"` and modify the line in your code to say `(Button)findViewById(R.id.someButtonId)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Sorin. I now get the following error: The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})

Comment: Sorin, sorted out the error message, i was not importing: import android.view.View.OnClickListener; It now crashes though when I click the The Company button ...

Comment: Unfortunately it's difficult to tell what the error is exactly without looking at the logs in LogCat. Intuition makes me think that the intent can't find the activity you're trying to launch. I imagine you have the line `Intent intent = new Intent(this, TheCompany.class);` inside your OnClickListener. Try replacing `this` with `MainActivity.this` so it looks like: `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TheCompany.class);` and see if it works. Otherwise I'd need some logs to see what it might be.